# Color each word in the cell with inputbox and multiple words in it at once

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have almost the same macro from other thread [Here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/864223-highlight-text-only-not-cell-in-a-certain-color-2.html). And now I am trying to add Inputbox where I am able to write the same that are in the code under Mylist without having to write each word in the code. But I found the difficulties to quote each word in the inputbox to get colored words. I can color only one word and I am stuck how to quote each word in inputbox separately.

Here is my edited code from an original thread:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub test()
    Dim myList, myColor, myPtn As String, r As Range, m As Object, msg As String, x
'    Application.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    msg = Application.InputBox("Choose keywords to highlight (max 6) that are separated with commas and space", "Input keywords", , , , , , 2)
    myList = VBA.Array(msg)  '<-- add more if needed
    myColor = VBA.Array(vbRed, vbBlue, vbYellow, vbCyan, vbGreen, vbMagenta) '<-- adjust as per myList(use Color value, not ColorIndex)
    myPtn = Join$(myList, Chr(2))
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "([\^\$\(\)\[\]\*\+\-\?\.\|])"
        myPtn = Replace(.Replace(myPtn, "\$1"), Chr(2), "|")
        .Pattern = "\b(" & myPtn & ")\b"
        For Each r In Application.Selection
            If .test(r.Value) Then
                For Each m In .Execute(r.Value)
                    x = Application.Match(m, myList)
                    If Not IsError(x) Then
                        r.Characters(m.firstindex + 1, m.Length).Font.Color = myColor(x - 1)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is:

```
 myList = VBA.Array("word1", "word2")
```

But the problem you are facing is because the value of the *InputBox* is returned as a single string. The result is:

```
msg = "word1, word2"
myList = VBA.Array("word1, word2")
```

So you will only search for that specific string.

The easiest way to go around this problem using this code, is by using the `Split` function.
`Split (string, delimiter, limit, compare)`

Split will take a string, split it, and return it as an array, which is exactly what you want. By changing

```
myList = VBA.Array(msg)
```

to

```
myList = Split(msg, ", ")
```

**Word limit**

If you want a limit to the amount of keywords, you could add a check on the amount of entered keywords using:

```
Application.CountA(myList)
```

And limit it with an "`If Application.CountA(myList) > 6 Then`" or similar.

**Selection safety**

Another thing you might want to add, is a limit on the amount of selected cells to run the code on.
If the user decides to "select all" before using this, their excel will most likely be out of commission for hours unless they force close the program.
A simple:

```
If Application.Selection.Count > 1000 Then
```

Or similar, followed by either a warning or a full stop would probably be wise.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and advices. It works great. Thanks a lot.